# How to accomplish pendulum effect using the accelerometer in an iOS App

Tags: ipad, ios, physics, accelerometer, gravity

By no means I am a physics expert. I am writing an iOS (iPad to be precise) App which will present a door knob sign, hanging off a (surprise) door knob. What I need to accomplish is to simulate a pendulum effect on the sign whenever the device gets moved around using the accelerometer.

Is it necessary for me to use a full-blown physics engine for this? If so, which one would you recommend? Or can I just make use of a couple of well-known and defined formula?

As usual, thanks to you all.

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kevin Sylvestre's pointer gives a good explanation for calculating the pendulum motion once the pivot point and the starting head angle are set. What you should add to your simulation is a dependency of the initial angle on the magnitude of acceleration that is measured with the horizontal accelerometer. A very simple relationship is to set `To = K*Ax`, where `To` is the initial angle (Theta_zero), `K` is a proportion constant and `Ax` is the horizontal accelerometer measurement. Thus when an impact is sensed, the pendulum starts to oscillate in a magnitude relative to the impact.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Sorry it took me this long to get back to you, I moved into a new house and lots of stuff happened in between. Unfortunately I am no longer in need of implementing this, but I will keep it for future reference if the chance ever appears to have it made at some point in the future. Anyways, I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The physics aren't too bad for this. A great demo in Java exists [here](http://www.myphysicslab.com/pendulum1.html).